# get count of records from associated table in cakephp 2.4

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-2.4

I just created the sample blog application which is running good.

But in addition to this i want to display the counts of the comments for each blog on blog listing page.

How could i get this?

Tables are:

1. blogs
2. comments

each blog may have many comments. this is i need to get i.e. how many comments for a particular blogs are there.

Comment: your question is not clear, you should have to mention your tables also, so that we can give answer

Answer (score 1):

### Use counter cache

One simple way to achieve that, assuming the comment belongs to blog, is to use [counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count).

That means adding a field for storing the counts to your blogs table:

```
alter table blogs add comment_count int(11) default 0;
```

Adding counter cache to the association definition for comments:

```
class Comment extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Blog' => array(
            'counterCache' => true,
        )
    );

}
```

And then, whenever a comment is created or deleted the comment_count field value will be updated in the blogs table.